# Permission Denied Error when Deploying RoR App on Phusion Passenger/Apache/Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

Deploying a RoR app on:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Ruby 1.9.3
- Apache 2
- Phusion Passenger 4.0.8
- Rails 4.0.0

I'm deploying as user root just to try things out. When I run Apache and hit the app, I get his error in my log/production.log (and of course Rails' HTTP 500 HTML appears on the browser):

```
F, [2013-10-24T21:54:50.253917 #29204] FATAL -- : 
Errno::EACCES (Permission denied - /depot/tmp/cache):
  app/views/store/index.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_store_index_html_erb___649405275_79899210'
```

I did some searching and it may be a user permissions issue. I looked at the users running the various process on my server. Here's a `top` dump:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                
    1 root      20   0  3520 1696 1276 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.76 init                                                                                   
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                               
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.36 ksoftirqd/0                                                                            
    5 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.12 kworker/u:0                                                                            
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0                                                                            
    7 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.14 watchdog/0                                                                             
    8 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuset                                                                                 
    9 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper                                                                                
   10 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs                                                                              
   11 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 netns                                                                                  
   12 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.04 sync_supers                                                                            
   13 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bdi-default                                                                            
   14 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd                                                                            
   15 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd                                                                                
   16 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ata_sff                                                                                
   17 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khubd                                                                                  
   18 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 md                                                                                     
   20 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.25 kworker/u:1                                                                            
   21 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khungtaskd                                                                             
   22 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.65 kswapd0                                                                                
   23 root      25   5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksmd                                                                                   
   24 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 fsnotify_mark                                                                          
   25 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ecryptfs-kthrea                                                                        
   26 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 crypto                                                                                 
   34 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthrotld                                                                               
   37 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_0                                                                              
   38 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_1                                                                              
   58 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 devfreq_wq                                                                             
  248 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.57 jbd2/vda-8                                                                             
  249 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ext4-dio-unwrit                                                                        
  313 root      20   0  2816  428  428 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.05 upstart-udev-br                                                                        
  316 root      20   0  3088  724  724 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.03 udevd                                                                                  
  411 root      20   0  3084  276  272 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 udevd                                                                                  
  412 root      20   0  3084  280  276 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 udevd                                                                                  
  426 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kpsmoused                                                                              
  553 root      20   0  2828  200  196 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 upstart-socket-                                                                        
  580 messageb  20   0  3240  428  428 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 dbus-daemon                                                                            
  622 syslog    20   0 30020 1008  952 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.71 rsyslogd                                                                               
  636 root      20   0  4612  776  656 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 getty                                                                                  
  637 root      20   0  4612  776  656 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 getty                                                                                  
  650 root      20   0  4612  772  656 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 getty                                                                                  
  651 root      20   0  4612  768  656 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 getty                                                                                  
  655 root      20   0  4612  776  656 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 getty                                                                                  
  663 root      20   0  2156  592  496 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 acpid                                                                                  
  664 root      20   0  2600  848  680 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.02 cron                                                                                   
  666 daemon    20   0  2452  344  220 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 atd                                                                                    
  745 root      20   0  6664 2348 1912 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.00 sshd                                                                                   
  751 root      20   0  4612  776  660 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 getty                                                                                  
 7272 mysql     20   0  319m  36m 7044 S  0.0  7.5   0:03.82 mysqld                                                                                 
 7625 root      20   0  8176 4352 2688 S  0.0  0.9   0:00.82 apache2                                                                                
28278 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 flush-253:0                                                                            
28554 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.05 kworker/0:2                                                                            
28681 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.05 kworker/0:0                                                                            
28970 root      20   0 11408 3340 2616 S  0.0  0.7   0:00.04 sshd                                                                                   
28984 depot     20   0 11408 1560  832 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.02 sshd                                                                                   
28985 depot     20   0 10168 6552 1596 S  0.0  1.3   0:00.35 bash                                                                                   
29102 www-data  20   0  8216 2208  524 S  0.0  0.4   0:00.00 apache2                                                                                
29103 root      20   0  7256 1704 1504 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.00 PassengerWatchd                                                                        
29106 root      20   0 34652 2868 2376 S  0.0  0.6   0:00.17 PassengerHelper                                                                        
29111 nobody    20   0 16992 3776 3032 S  0.0  0.7   0:00.00 PassengerLoggin                                                                        
29121 www-data  20   0  225m 2628  840 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.00 apache2                                                                                
29122 www-data  20   0  226m 3412 1556 S  0.0  0.7   0:00.00 apache2                                                                                
29185 www-data  20   0 48496  39m 3852 S  0.0  7.9   0:02.97 ruby1.9.1                                                                              
29204 www-data  20   0 68052  47m 3972 S  0.0  9.5   0:00.24 ruby1.9.1                                                                              
29229 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 kworker/0:1                                                                            
29321 depot     20   0  2720 1048  844 R  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 top
```

You can see that apache2 is running under "root" and "www-data" users, and that ruby is running under the "www-data" user. I've tried to change the ownership of the application directory to both "root" and "www-data" to no avail.

Comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255335/phusion-passenger-error-permission-denied-for-gemfile-lock) seem to suggest that deploying under "root" could be the cause of the problem. I'm assuming this means that I have to reinstall my ruby, apache, and passenger as a user other than root. This seems a bit extreme if I'm missing something else that's simpler.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I can't claim to know linux user permissions, but what worked for me was reinstalling apache, passenger, ruby, rails, the app, and all dependencies as a user *different from root*. That seemed to fix the problem and the permission denied issue did not arise.

**Update**
I should amend my solution by mentioning that I rebuilt the server and did a fresh install of all the above under the non-root user (so I didn't reinstall anything really, I recreated the whole stack from scratch).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, this is the effect of the automatic user switching feature. See http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#user_switching for answers.

With "deploying under root" he did not mean that Passenger was installed as root. He meant that his *application* was owned by root. The documentation clearly explains what happens in that scenario: Passenger will refuse to run the app as root for security reasons, and will run the app as "PassengerDefaultUser" instead (which defaults to www-data on your machine).

Comment: I don't know, I changed the ownership of the entire to app directory to www-data and it didn't work. I think I just got it working by rebuilding the setup with a non-root user. If I can get it completely working I'll post the solution here.